# jni: call object method on jclass

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I came across this code

```
    jclass mainClass = env->FindClass("com/example/MainActivity");
    jclass classClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Class");
    jclass classLoaderClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/ClassLoader");
    jmethodID getClassLoaderMethod = env->GetMethodID(classClass, "getClassLoader", "()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;");
    jobject classLoader = env->CallObjectMethod(mainClass, getClassLoaderMethod);
    jmethodID findClassMethod = env->GetMethodID(classLoaderClass, "findClass", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;");
```

and to my surprise it is actually working. classLoader and findClassMethod are valid and can be used for subsequent calls to java.

Can someone explain why the `CallObjectMethod` line is working here, since the method getClassLoader is an object method, but it is called on a jclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader()) is an instance method of `java.lang.Class`, hence you need use `CallObjectMethod` and pass it a `Class` instance. What you have in `mainClass` is an instance of `Class` (specifically an instance of `Class<MainActivity>`).

Comment: I still don't get it completely. My understanding is that i need to call `getClassLoader` on an instance of `Class` (for example an instance of `MainActivity`).But `FindClass` returns a reference to the class, not any instance of the class

Comment: I gave the JNI documentation another read after your hint and I think i got it now. `FindClass` will return an object of type `Class<MainActivity>` and thus I can call instance methods of `Class`.